# AMQPConnectionClosedException: Broken pipe or closed connection

Tags: rabbitmq, magento2, amqp

I wrote a microservice application in PHP, where microservices communicate with each other using queues in RabbitMQ (each microservice has its own queue).

There was a problem: if you send more than 700 messages from one microservice to another at once, then an error appears: "PHP Fatal error: Uncaught PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPConnectionClosedException: Broken pipe or closed connection in ".../vendor/php-amqplib/php- amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php:171", the application stops working, and messages in the queue disappear.

When sending 40-60 messages, there is no problem.

-

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your callback function, which receives messages from RabbitMQ in the microservice, tries to take and process all messages at once, but it fails, and this error appears.

Try reconfiguring the queue connection and processing the messages one at a time. It's also worth checking that the "acknowledgment" option is enabled, preventing the next message from being taken until the current one has been processed.

More details on setting up the queue:

1. in the PhpAmqpLib\Channel\AMQPChannel::basic_qos($prefetch_size, $prefetch_count, $a_global) method, it is important to pass the $prefetch_count = 1 parameter to process messages one by one;
2. in method PhpAmqpLib\Channel\AMQPChannel::basic_consume($queue = '', $consumer_tag = '', $no_local = false, $no_ack = false, $exclusive = false, $nowait = false, $callback = null, $ticket = null, $arguments = array()) it is important that the $no_ack parameter remains false. The parameter is responsible for enabling confirmation of each received message;
3. after the message from the queue has been processed, you need to call the PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage::ack() method on it. Without calling this method, the next message from the queue cannot be taken.

All information is in the official RabbitMQ documentation https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-php.html